# Given $N, b$ find the largest value of $k$ such that $N=a \times b^k$. $a,b,k,N \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to find a function that produces $k$ in this problem using $N$ and $b$ as inputs.

Given $N, b$ find the largest value of $k$ such that $N=a \times b^k$. $a,b,k,N \in \mathbb{Z}$

My instinct is that this is not possible.

E.g. If $N=300$ and $b=10$ then $k=2$ since $300=3\times10^2$

Is there a name for this concept? I've struggled to google anything useful / relevant.

Comment: Why should this not possible (as long as you exclude cases such as $b=1$ or $N=0$)? You just defined that function successfully. - In particular for prime $b$, this goes by the name *$p$-adic valuation*

Comment: What do you mean by closed form? I don't think that's possible here. However if you're programming it or something similar, something like "While N is divisible by b, divide N by b and increment the answer" would give you the result.

Comment: @GarethMa I do not wish to use a program. I meant analytic function
, not closed form.

Comment: p-adics seem to be what I was after. Thank you @HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k$ is the $b$-adic order of $N$.

It would be difficult to find a function that delivers $k$ from a given $N, b$, however $k$ is easily calculated by repeadtedly dividing $N$ by $b$ until it would give a  fraction.  In your example, we see that $\frac{300}{10^2}=3$, but $\frac{300}{10^3}=0.3\not\in\Bbb Z$, and so $k=2$

Comment: This points me in a useful direction, thank you.